# Javascript Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can't understand why the following data which I obtained from a JSON does not get added to Google Maps, but the commented one, which has hard-coded vaules, does. Can anyone give any advice, or suggest a method to put several markers on a map from json data ?

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(respData));    
for (var k in obj) {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: parseFloat(obj[1].latitude),
    lng: parseFloat(obj[1].longitude)
  };                       
  //var myLatLng = {lat: 46.7693924, lng: 23.5902006};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

Comment: A few questions. Why are you stringifying then parsing some JSON? `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(respData))` is pointless. Second: a `for..in` loop goes through the keys in an object. Why are you doing this but never using the key `k`?

Comment: Did you run your code in debugger checking if myLatLng has values you expect?

Comment: Add a `console.log(obj)` in before `var myLatLng` and ensure that `obj` is what you expected. Adding this data to the question would help get an answer. Is it your intention to access the second element in the array, or should you be using `obj[0].latitude`?

Comment: What does your data look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [The posted code works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kj9ea9uu/) (when I provide the missing pieces), your error is likely outside of the code you posted.

Comment: I used index 1 just for testing purposes, it would normally be k. As for  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(respData)), I guess I didn't understand how these things actually worked, I just wanted to obtain latitude and longitude from that json that contains userId and id as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(respData));  
console.log(obj);  
for (var k in obj) {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: parseFloat(obj[k].latitude),
    lng: parseFloat(obj[k].longitude)
  };                       
  //var myLatLng = {lat: 46.7693924, lng: 23.5902006};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

and tell us what the console says

Comment: That's not going to work. `k` is a string, not an object containing `latitude` and `longitude`.

Comment: well if you tell us what the console says when I logged obj, I would be able to help - and have that piece of information as well if its true

Comment: It is true. [It's always true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). That's how `for..in` works. But you are right that seeing the contents of `obj` would be helpful.

Comment: I fixed the syntax oversight.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the value I was giving was out of range...I should brush up on geography.